# UI-GRID display json data

Tags: angularjs, json, typescript, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

At the moment I am retrieving data from the server.

```
[
  {
    id:1, 
    name:demo,
    request: {
      id: 1,
      localCompany: {
        id: 1
      }
   }
}]
```

[{ }, { }] so this is how my json object looks.

When I get call the $http service and put it in the gridOptions: {data: this.data}
I get this error in the console window: **TypeError: newRawData.forEach is not a function**.

```
 data: ng.IPromise<any[]> = this.programService.getRequestsForProgram(this.model.id).then((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });

gridOptions: {} = {
        data: this.data ,
        paginationPageSize: 5
        //columnDefs: this.programCountryService.getHeaders()
    };
```

This is the code I am using at the moment.

Any idea how I can get rid of this error? And is it possible that the grid only shows localCompany.Id and not the name:demo?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the data in $scope.data

Like $scope.data=getdata from server

and then

gridOptions: {} = {
        data: $scope.data ,
        paginationPageSize: 5
        //columnDefs: this.programCountryService.getHeaders()
    };

Answer (score 0):

Put `data` into `$scope` and than to `gridOptions.data = $scope.data`.

If you want to show only data for localCompany.id you need to make definition for `columnDefs` for field `request` with custom template like:

```
'<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{ COL_FIELD.id }}</div>'
```